# Работа с почтовыми сообщениями

Tags: gmail

Ситуация следующая. Я студент 4-курса. Мой дипломный руководитель предложил мне сделать следующий проект: суть такая -  ему на почту приходят письма для принятия участия в различных научных проектах, типа УМНИК. Так вот он хочет, чтобы был сайт, на который эти письма выгружаются в виде новостей. Т.е., чтобы не на почту ему каждый раз лазить и искать нужные, а учитывая большое количество подобных проектов и спамящий момент остальных писем, это крайне не удобно. Поэтому преподаватель поставил задачу автоматизировать данный процесс (поиск писем только нужной тематики и дальнейшая выгрузка их на сайт) и расшарить инфу через сайт. Т.е как только ему на почту пришло письмо, оно через некоторые время появляется на сайте в виде новости. И другие преподаватели ВУЗА могли бы зайти и посмотреть, когда и какие ближайшие конкурсы будут порводиться. А в дальнейшем, если кого-то заинтересовало, то человек просто переходят на оригинальный сайт и там уже более детально изучают информацию. На перспективу, на сайте должны быть новости со всех научных проектов, на которые преподаватель оформил подписку.

Может, у google есть какое-нибудь API с подобным функционалом? Или кто-нибудь знает, где почитать статьи по реализации похожий решений?

Comment: api google - https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/

Comment: а почитать о IMAP ? gmail это обычный (ну почти) почтовый сервис и с ним можно работать обычными методами. Если все сделать правильно, то парситься почта будет почти в режиме реального времени:)

Comment: дело в том, что при парсинге тела письма начинаются проблемы с кодировкой